# Problems With Comparing Strings

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code that was working a few days ago but then all the sudden, without any changes being made, gave me all these errors. Any help in troubleshooting would be appreciated.

```
init(name: String, arrayOfNodes: [SKSpriteNode]){

var SKnode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cool Image")

SKnode.name = name     //Error: Cannot apply value of type String to type String

for(node in arrayOfNodes){   //4 errors about random things like putting in commas at various points
    //Stuff
}

if(name == "Billy"){   //Binary operator "==" cannot be applied to operands of type String and String
    //Stuff
}
```

None of these errors seem right to me and they came about without any changes being made to the file. I've tried restarting Xcode, restarting the computer, none of it changes the error messages.

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis from your `for..in` statement, they shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks, that takes care of those errors, but any ideas for the others?

Comment: Also, the init method for `SKSpriteNode` should be `SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: )`

Comment: Sorry most of this is just code I filled in. The errors I'm really trying to address are the String to String ones.

Comment: You should post more of the class and code surrounding this method, something else is going on outside of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, you had extra parenthesis in your `for..in` statement, you didn't declare your variable `SKnode` (which the convention is to name in initial lower case so it doesn't conflict with [`SKNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/)), and the proper label for the init of `SKSpriteNode` is `imageNamed`.

Once those errors are fixed I don't get any further issues. Perhaps your problems stem from other issues in your class or code?

My corrected code:

```
import SpriteKit

class Foo {
  init(name: String, arrayOfNodes: [SKSpriteNode]){

    let skNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cool Image")

    skNode.name = name

    for node in arrayOfNodes {
      //Stuff
    }

    if(name == "Billy"){
      //Stuff
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've copied and pasted this exact same code into a new file but it has the same error messages as I was encountering with the String to String thing.

Comment: It sounds like you might have extended or redefined `String` somewhere. Do you have any other context you can share?

Comment: Ohhhhh... Thanks a lot. I had made a class called String that was referring to a literal piece of string and I was stupid enough not to catch it.

Comment: No problem, you should also watch out for a conflict between your variable `SKNode` and the class [`SKNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/)

Comment: @ulthran Indeed, you need to not ever use class names that conflict with existing class names. String, SKNode, Set, Dictionary, all bad. Stop and think when you define a new class. Is there ANY chance my name might be defined by a system framework? If so, make it unique. Lots of people use 3 character prefixes from their project names, or their initials, or SOMETHING to make the class names unique. Swift's error messages can be bizarre and misleading. i'm hoping that gets better as the language matures, but it can be very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Well part of the problem is the parenthesizes in your `for` loop. Remove them. Apple recommends that types start with a capital so your `SKnode` may be legal as a variable name but it is confusing to others. I am not sure about the other two errors.

Why isn't the parameter label in SKSpriteNode like this; `SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cool Image")`?